# handling WYSIWYG data in PHP

Tags: php, wysiwyg, htmlspecialchars

I need to use a wysiwyg editor for handling user input.

How do you process this in php?

If I retrieve the data and use htmlspecialchars then all the characters that were converted to special characters by the wysiwyg editor will be messed up.

For example quote will be `&quote;`

When I use `htmlspecialchars` in php the & will be converted to `&amp;`

It will be an obvious problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I see your problem. `&` is converted to `&`? If `htmlspecialchars` messes up your editor, then why do you need to use it when pulling data for the editor?

Comment: for example if input was coming from plain text and i use htmlspecialchars then '&' would look like '&' but if i use the wysiwyg then it converts '&' to '&amp;' that's ok but if i use htmlspecialchars as a precaution (in case this was a malicious user) then the user would not see from '&amp;' - '&' but rather the text would become '&ampamp;' . make sense?

Comment: Assuming your editor requires HTML, I would suggest [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It will clean up script tags and other things which could cause problems, while allowing you to use HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered keeping a plain-text and an additional HTML record of whatever is being modified? You can display the plaintext and when you save it you could convert it to html also and save that in a seperate field?

If special chars are being converted to HTML though, wouldn't they still appear properly (to the user) when you are printing text out to editable form fields in html?

Let me know if I've misunderstood

Comment: problem is the wysiwyg editor converts the plain text BEFORE submitting. It submits to the php script the converted text. So if I output that intact it should be good. But if I use htmlspecialchars then it would mess up the special codes. But the question is that this is not secure. A hacker could submit plain html.

Answer (score 0):

Most editors (CKEditor, CLEditor and NicEdit to mention a few) supports two modes of input: Visual and direct input (usually called HTML mode).

When the user is entering text in visual mode, the editor takes care of converting html-like characters to the respective HTML entity while the user is typing his/her content. In this mode, the editor will typically add markup for the user (mostly paragraphs).

Direct input works like you'd expect from the name; The user is exposed to the HTML his or her content is made up of.

How you should handle the input data depends mostly on the users role.

If the user is trusted (i.e. an administrator for a company website), the user should be able to use both input modes.

If the user is untrusted (an anonymous user posting a comment on a blog post), the user should not be able to input (potentially malicious, think [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) markup.

If your users needs some options for formatting their content, you should probably look into using another type of markup, e.g [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode). This prevents the user from injecting any `<script>` tags into the content that might be shown to other users.

You will still need to strip any HTML tags from the user content though.

Comment: do you know which editor uses raw input? From what i've seen, people copy/paste from their word applications so right quotes get converted to characters codes with an ampersand at the beginning. using htmlspecialchars to display would mess that up

Comment: I've completely misunderstood your question then. I'll revise my anwer.

Comment: here's more clarification. thanks alot for your help. for example if input was coming from plain text and i use htmlspecialchars then '&' would be outputed as '&amp;' but if i use the wysiwyg then it converts '&' to '&amp;' that's ok but if i use htmlspecialchars as a precaution (in case this was a malicious user) then the user would not see from '&amp;' - '&' but rather the text would become '&ampamp;' . make sense?